# How my design should handle bulkupload csv

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have architecture design flaw, so want to remove that.

Problem statement: I have a CSV for bulk upload which contains 100 or more rows, these rows are added into sqs (not in order) to consume and hit an API and get the response and save it to mysql DB, if fail then it send the mail for every fail api.

But I want rather than 100 of email a single mail of fail api was sent

Comment: If you have a database record for each upload, you could add fields which record the failure and indicate if an e-mail has been sent.

Comment: So which bit of this do you need help with?

Comment: Actually insertion part in php but consumer is written in java, api give response one by one, there is a mail api to hit if api send fail response

Comment: Resolved, made a solution, rather than insertion of 100 tickets, add one ticket in sqs (by php module) , then (java module) consumer read it execute the rows insert in DB after finish hit a api for send email, then again PHP module checked the current failed then send a single shot email.

Comment: Thanks for helping me guyz which lead me to a solutions

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out a way to track the 100th row (job) processing so that you can perform "send email" task finally. You can achieve it in the following way

Maintain one record in new MYSQL table with colums sucess_apis, failure_apis, total_apis, and no_apis_completed

After processing of each job (row) by SQS consumer,  increment the counts   no_apis_completed , sucess_apis count (if sucesses), failure_apis (if failed)  count by one

Before processing any job fetch the no_apis_completed column value and if the currently processing job is 100th one then you can send emails 
**OR**  you can also sumbit entry to SQS queue with different task name and then you can have module in SQS consumer to perform "send email" action on receiving task with send email type